# how to remove divider between items of Recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, divider

i want to remove divider (space) between items of RecyclerView

So try to set `background` of item view and `RecyclerView` to `White`,but it doesn't works
how to fix it ?

Item View `XML` :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/footer_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/footer_item_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_avatar_category_item_adapter"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width_category_adapter"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Activity XML :

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_categories_main_activity"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`Activity` Class :

```
    rv_categories.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    rv_categories.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

[image]

Comment: remove       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/footer_item_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/footer_item_padding"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> First define your RecyclerView :
>
> RecyclerView recycle =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
>
> and in your activity use this method:

```
recycle.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, 0));
```

Comment: can we not remove it in XML directly ?

Comment: this will set the divider horizontally but doesn't remove completely the divider

Comment: Its meaningful to use LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE rather than 0 here

Answer (score 9):

You can use `DividerItemDecoration` class and override its `onDraw` method to do nothing like so:

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            // Do not draw the divider
        }
    });
```

Comment: Finally, I found a solution :D

Comment: What if we want to draw for certain rows but not others?

Comment: @lostintranslation I suggest you use method `getChildAt()` on `RecyclerView` to get visible `View`. Then call `getChildAdapterPosition()` with the `View` you got from the previous step as a parameter. Then judging by the position value you get, you apply your logic for drawing for this particular view.
What to pass to `getChildAt()`? I suppose creating a while loop from 0 until that method return `null` will do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the other answers didn't work for me but this workaround did:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getItemDecorationCount(); i++) {
    if (recyclerView.getItemDecorationAt(i) instanceof DividerItemDecoration)
        recyclerView.removeItemDecorationAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Removes horizontal and vertical separators. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use below line of code in your code, its solve the iisue

groceryRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));

or

recycle.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, 0));

Comment: Only removing the code will work. Setting to 0 will not remove the devider. I tested.

Comment: This answers the question. It should be ticked.

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

to recyclerView xml.

Comment: No such property